# c# database architecture

Tags: c#, database, architecture

I am planning to build an equipment maintenance application. I am going to use C# and WPF with Access or SQL database(s). This single application is going to handle many projects (facilities).

My question is: What is the best approach...

- create separate databases for each project
- have one (much more complex) database which will handle all facilities

Comment: I would use **one** database, and I don't expect that to be "much more complex" just because of that one additional requirement.....

Comment: There isn't enough detail to answer this question. How many concurrent users will the application have? Will you need to report on all projects in one place? Why do you think you need to use multiple databases?

Comment: If you don't need to share, combine or report on data between facilities, then I would tend toward separate database and SQLLite. If you want to combine the data in any way, then a SQL server of some type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is a specific requirement for it to be separate databases, do not separate them. In the end it will turn out to be much more maintenance effort to have all these databases (how do you know each one is backed up and restorable? What happens when the structure changes, how do you apply the changes to each database in a safe way? etc)

What seems complex right now (having a single database) will be much simpler in the long run.

Comment: Do you have any tutorial, example or pattern how to build this database/app. Not asking about this specific task rather a general approach?

Answer (score 0):

Using single database for the equipment maintenance application would be better. Have a look on below link too as similar scenario have discussed before:
[Any gain on performance when using single vs multiple databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912544/any-gain-on-performance-when-using-single-vs-multiple-databases)

Feel free to ask further questions if arises. Thanks.